# Matrix multiplication of each row in data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, matrix-multiplication

This should be elementary, but cannot get my head around it.
I have a data frame and want to create a new variable as the matrix multiplication of each row by a pre-specified vector.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(matrix(1:6,2))
vector <- c(1,0,1)

##NOT WORKING
data <- data %>%
mutate(multiplication = as.numeric(data[,]) %*% vector)

mm <- function(x,y){
  n <- as.numeric(x)
  m <- n %*% y
  print(as.numeric(m))
}

##NOT WORKING
data$mm <- lapply(data[,], function(x) mm(x,vector))
```

Comment: @user20650 so in base R:  `data$multiplication <- as.matrix(data) %*% vector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```r
data %>% mutate(multiplication = apply(., 1, function(x) x %*% vector))
#>   X1 X2 X3 multiplication
#> 1  1  3  5              6
#> 2  2  4  6              8
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

```
data %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(multiplication = sum(c_across(everything()) * vector))

     X1    X2    X3 multiplication
  <int> <int> <int>          <dbl>
1     1     3     5              6
2     2     4     6              8
```

Answer (score 0):

use `as.matrix`

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(matrix(1:6,2))
vector <- c(1,0,1)

data %>%
  mutate(multiplication = as.matrix(data[,]) %*% vector)
#>   X1 X2 X3 multiplication
#> 1  1  3  5              6
#> 2  2  4  6              8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can use `crossprod` from `base R`

```
data$multiplication <- crossprod(t(data), vector)[,1]
```

-output

```
data
#  X1 X2 X3 multiplication
#1  1  3  5              6
#2  2  4  6              8
```